# How to hide the navigation bar in both my activities without make it visible in between?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am developing an app in Android-studio where I have two activities I am going back and forth from. It's a fullscreen app, so I have added this "immersive" code to my onCreate-method to both of my activities, to hide the action- and navigation bars from showing.

```
       @Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (hasFocus) {
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
    }
}
```

They are successfully hidden. However, my problem is that the bars show for 0.3 seconds every time I switch activity, and it makes it bad looking. Do you guys have a solution to make it look smooth? Thanks for help!

Comment: can you please add screen shot

Comment: It is very hard to get a screenshot of the problem, because it disappears so quickly. If it was difficult to understand my question I will try to explain better

Answer (score 1):

May be using a fullscreen theme from style for both the activities will help. instead of doin it in runtime.
values/styles.xml

```
    <resources> 
   <style name="CodeFont" parent="android:Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
      <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item> 
      ...
   </style>
</resources>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity 
    android:name=".MainActivity" 
    android:theme="@style/CodeFont"> 
      ...
</activity>
```